# Why is the default font of numbers so poor?

Tags: discussion, font

When I'm choosing to write a number on math.se, why is the default font like 314159 and not like $314159$?

I find it quite annoying to have to write `$314159$` every time. I can't think of a single case where the first font would be preferred over the latter.

> Why isn't the default font like this: $314159$?

Comment: I am glad someone asked this. Puzzling SE has very nice numbers in its default font, why not MSE as well?

Comment: The font in Puzzling SE looks like it's of the sans serif variety. So it's not just the numbers that look different to how they do here. How do different SE sites end up with different (default) fonts?

Comment: Relevant post: [Why does the font use text figures ("lowercase digits")?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10317/888233)

Comment: I thought this question was about the new [tiny numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh8yM.png) in the new top bar notifications. Was ready to go off...

Comment: @Calvin Feel free to "go off..." in a question here.  They add bright icons, but [tiny numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh8yM.png).  For that second change, "better visibility" is thereby ruled out.

Comment: SE is not, and never was originally, designed as a mathematics network.  SE has enabled sites dealing with numbers, formulas, operators, greek numbers, etc., etc., through mathjax.  Most sites on the network don't use it, nor need it, including in the lists numerically ordered.  Math.se is a fraction of SE.  It was founded originally, to support stack overflow, computing, programming, etc.  As far back as 2010, SE made mathjax available, recognizing it's importance to sites like ours.  Programming sites require ``foo`` or indenting, for coding.  A dollar sign on each end ain't much to ask.

Comment: Survey, EL&U, or any non-math oriented site (a hundred and more sites, to be honest, and check whether there are complaints about numbers not looking like they do in mathjax.  I encourage you, anonymous, to ask this question on [meta.se] where it belongs.

Comment: What looks good is entirely a matter of taste.  For what it is worth, I actually prefer the non-MathJax numerals (0123456789)---I find the variation in height and the descenders to be an aid to readability.  But if it really bothers you, it should be possible to create a custom stylesheet which changes the way in which your browser renders the site (it should require only a small change in order to swap the default font here for something else).